# Date T & Z format

Tags: php, datetime

```
$date = "2017-04-28T20:12:55Z";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date))."\n";
```

outputs `2017-04-29 01:42:55` - How can I know in which timezone, $date is represented in ?

Comment: If you put `e` or `T` in your format string, it will get replaced with the timezone. See the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) page for other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z is the timezone and it's the abreviation of Zulu Time Zone

And in general, to get the timezone of a date you can use:

```
 $date = new DateTime($aStringDate);
 echo $date->format('T');
```

Comment: Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC" is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "T0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would be "14:45:15Z" or "T144515Z".
The Z suffix in the ISO 8601 time representation is sometimes referred to as "Zulu time" or "Zulu meridian" because the same letter is used to designate the Zulu time zone. However the ACP 121 standard that defines the list of military time zones makes no mention of UTC and derives the "Zulu time" from the Greenwich Mean Time which was formerly used as the international civil time standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601